# Sqoop export to Teradata failing with error - Task attempt failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing

Tags: hadoop, teradata, cloudera, sqoop

I am facing tasks attempts failing with below error, related to Teradata export (batch insert) jobs.
Other jobs exporting data to Oracle etc. are running fine.

`Task attempt_1234_m_000000_0 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!,
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error at           org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:250) 
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=255: at  org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:543) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:460) at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:707)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LinuxTaskController.createLogDir(LinuxTaskController.java:313) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.prepareLogFiles(TaskRunner.java:295)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:215)`


I can also see below error message from task stdout logs :
`"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f8824018800 nid=0x3395 runnable [0x00007f882bffb000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.read(TDNetworkIOIF.java:693)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDPacketStream.readStream(TDPacketStream.java:774)`

Hadoop version : Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.3.8

Specifically it will be really helpful if you could tell me  why this issue is happening?
Is this an issue related to limit in number of connections  to Teradata ?

Comment: have you checked yarn logs?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Job is running in MR1, not yarn

Comment: check with -m 1 in the sqoop command.. if the error is because of the connection limit we can over come by giving this -m 1.

Comment: The issue is intermittent.i.e, most of the jobs are getting success, but few tasks attempts are failing with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause of the issue:
-Sqoop task is inserting around 4 million records into teradata and hence the task is bit long running
-The insert query ,since long running is going into Teradata delay qeueue (workload management at Teradata end - set by DBAs), and hence sqoop mapreduce task is not getting a response fro 600 sec.s from teradata 
-Since default task time-out is 600sec., the transaction was aborted by map task resulting in task failure
Ref: http://apps.teradata.com/TDMO/v08n04/Tech2Tech/TechSupport/RoadRules.aspx
Solution:
1-Increase Taks time-out at mapreduce end.
2-Change configuartions related to delay queue at teradata end for the sepecific user